# I have a plain text file with a list of filenames inside, I need to search for a string on each file from the list. How can I do it? In C#

Tags: c#, string, list, file, file-io

I have this file named "Files.txt" which contains a list of file names inside:

### ------Files.TXT------
TS0001.000
TS0002.000
TS0003.000 ...

I need to look for the string "Process Error" inside of the files in the mentioned list and output the filename and the error to a new file as a log.

How can I do it? Complete newbie here :)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you need to use c#? If all you're doing is creating a log file, this would probably be more suited for Powershell or Bash scripting.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please update your post to include what you've tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide complete information, so the solution may need to changed a bit based on your complete problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"c:\file.txt";
            var outPath = @"c:\error.log";
            var outs = new List<string>();
            string fileText = File.ReadAllText(path);

            foreach (var file in fileText.Split(" "))
            {
                var readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\" + file);

                foreach (string line in readText)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("Process Error"))
                    {
                        outs.Add(file);
                        outs.Add(line);

                    }
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(outPath, outs);
        }
    }
}
```